# How to detect objects shape from images using python3?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, opencv3.0

i want to write a code in python3 that detects objects shapes from images. 

I want to choose a pixel from an object in the given image and find the neighbours pixels. 

 
If they have the same RGB value that means that they are part of the object.

When neighbour pixel changes the RGB value with an ajustable difference from original pixel the algorithm should stop searching for neighbours. I think that this will work unless the backgroud and object have the same color.

I have found a way to put the pixels with same color in an rectangle,but this will not help me. I want to save just the shape of the object and put it in a different image. 

For example,

> If i want to start my algorithm from the middle of an object, let's
>   say a black table with a white background,the algorithm will find
>   pixels with the same color in any direction. 
> When the neighbour pixel
>   RGB values will change with more than 30 units in one direction,the
>   algorithm will stop going in that direction,and will start going in
>   another direction untill I have the shape of the table.

I found a code on another post that help me to determinate regions of pixels with a shared value using PIL

Thanks!

```
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw


def connected_components(edges):
"""
Given a graph represented by edges (i.e. pairs of nodes), generate its
connected components as sets of nodes.

Time complexity is linear with respect to the number of edges.
"""
neighbors = defaultdict(set)
for a, b in edges:
    neighbors[a].add(b)
    neighbors[b].add(a)
seen = set()
def component(node, neighbors=neighbors, seen=seen, see=seen.add):
    unseen = set([node])
    next_unseen = unseen.pop
    while unseen:
        node = next_unseen()
        see(node)
        unseen |= neighbors[node] - seen
        yield node
return (set(component(node)) for node in neighbors if node not in seen)


def matching_pixels(image, test):
"""
Generate all pixel coordinates where pixel satisfies test.
"""
  width, height = image.size
  pixels = image.load()
  for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        if test(pixels[x, y]):
            yield x, y


def make_edges(coordinates):
"""
Generate all pairs of neighboring pixel coordinates.
"""
  coordinates = set(coordinates)
  for x, y in coordinates:
      if (x - 1, y - 1) in coordinates:
          yield (x, y), (x - 1, y - 1)
      if (x, y - 1) in coordinates:
          yield (x, y), (x, y - 1)
      if (x + 1, y - 1) in coordinates:
        yield (x, y), (x + 1, y - 1)
      if (x - 1, y) in coordinates:
        yield (x, y), (x - 1, y)
      yield (x, y), (x, y)


def boundingbox(coordinates):
"""
Return the bounding box of all coordinates.
"""
  xs, ys = zip(*coordinates)
  return min(xs), min(ys), max(xs), max(ys)


def disjoint_areas(image, test):
"""
Return the bounding boxes of all non-consecutive areas
who's pixels satisfy test.
"""
  for each in connected_components(make_edges(matching_pixels(image, test))):
    yield boundingbox(each)


def is_black_enough(pixel):
  r, g, b = pixel
  return r < 10 and g < 10 and b < 10


if __name__ == '__main__':

  image = Image.open('some_image.jpg')
  draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
  for rect in disjoint_areas(image, is_black_enough):
      draw.rectangle(rect, outline=(255, 0, 0))
  image.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using opencv with Python.
With opencv you can make advanced image analysis and there are many tutorials to use it.
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/04/21/building-pokedex-python-finding-game-boy-screen-step-4-6/